# ForeignKey from base class model to inheritor error

Tags: python, django, orm, models

I want to make the next models architecture:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    """
    This is base class for all places like shops, trc, restaurants, etc.
    """
    name = models.CharField(_('Place name'), max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('Partner', verbose_name=_('Partner'), related_name='places')
    ...
    # next line causes errors
    trc = models.ForeignKey('Trc', related_name='places', null=True, blank=True) 


class Trc(Place):  # Trc is equal to Mall - place which contains shops, cafes, cinemas 
    ...

class Shop(Place):
    ...

class Restaurant(Place):
    ...
```

Adding 'trc' field in Place model will make querying nice and generic, but when I'm trying to create such tables in db, I'm getting the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
partner.trc: Accessor for field 'place_ptr' clashes with field 'Place.trc'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'place_ptr'.
partner.trc: Reverse query name for field 'place_ptr' clashes with field 'Place.trc'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'place_ptr'.
```

Playing with related name doesn't help... I really don't want to move 'trc' field in Shop and Restaurant. Thanks

Comment: This structure doesn't seem to make sense. Why would `Place` have a link to `trc`, which is one of its subclasses?

Comment: What @DanielRoseman said. Also, `Place` should probably be an abstract model.

Comment: In application code in most of cases should be no difference between types of places. For example if I want to get list of nearby Trc, Shops and Restaurant - I'm just making one simple query - Place.objects.filter(...). That's why I don't want to use abstract base class.

Comment: Yes, inheritance structure is a bit weird. In my case ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True) is the best decision. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add the `trc` field, because it will already exist. Check out the very similar example in the [django docs on multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

> If you have a `Place` that is also a `Restaurant`, **you can get from the** `Place` **object to the** `Restaurant` **object by using the lower-case version of the model name**:

```
    p = Place.objects.get(id=12)
    # If p is a Restaurant object, this will give the child class:
    p.restaurant
    <Restaurant: ...>
```

> However, if `p` in the above example was not a `Restaurant` (it had been
>   created directly as a `Place` object or was the parent of some other
>   class), referring to `p.restaurant would` raise a
>   `Restaurant.DoesNotExist` exception.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Place name'), max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('Partner', verbose_name=_('Partner'), related_name='places')
    ...
    # next line causes errors
    #trc = models.ForeignKey('Trc', related_name='places', null=True, blank=True) 


class Trc(Place):  # Trc is equal to Mall - place which contains shops, cafes, cinemas 
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='trc', ...)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to make generic decision - if some other place-type will be added (like Bank, Bar, Cinema) - I'll have to add them in all my API functions. My desire is to use only one line - Place.objects.filter(...) to get all of subclass models. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: No, that's not possible for any reasonable definition of possible.

Comment: You can use the party/relationship pattern (e.g. http://www.cse.fau.edu/~security/public/docs/CRMPattMar05.pdf) if you really want to be generic..

Comment: Ok, thanks... That's sad. Seems like it would be better to end up with  abstract class for places that could be contained in other places, some kind of mixin - Shop(Place, Containable).

Comment: I thought and found ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True) in Place  model is the best decision in my case.

Comment: I don't think that does what you want.. I would suggest forgetting about Django/Python for a minute and figure out how your schema is going to look in the database. Perhaps even draw som ER diagrams..?  Forward links to base-classes can work in a purely OO design if you put functionality in virtual methods inherited from the base -- or if you downcast to the actual type of the object. A self-join, however, will only get you Place records, not the sub-classes they represent and you'll end up implementing a downcast operator by iterating over all sub-classes.. imho, a horrible design choice.

Comment: Yes, good point. But I figured out that in this project I actually don't need sublasses like Shop/Restaurant/Cinema - all I need is Place and PlaceContainer with extra functionality which will be used in really few places. Thanks for helping, but seems like I'll use your advices in other projects, not in this one!)